# Validating Existing Code from Database in Ajax Call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am not getting why my code is not working. I am trying to validate a code by calling a function in controller. if this code already exists i simply sent 'failed' text and then i want the form to stop its submission. but this does not work. even i get failed error my forms does not stopping itself by getting submitted.

here is the code for view

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupform').submit(function () {

        var code = $('#txtcode').val();
        alert(code);
        if (code.length > 0) {

            //validate email
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@(Url.Action("CheckCode", "Home"))",
                data: {
                    "code": code,
                    "type": "Data"
                },
                success: function (returndata) {
                    if (returndata.match('failed')) {
                        alert(returndata);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Form**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ManipuleInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "signupform", name = "signupform" }))
{
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Code:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code, new { @id = "txtcode", @name = "txtcode", @required = "required" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Title:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Sub- Type:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubType, listItemsmode)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Subscriber Type:
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubscriberType, listItemstypes)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label> Live:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Published)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <label> Press add button to start adding fields!</label>
                    <table id="Controls" style="display: none"></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div style="text-align:right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btnStyle" name="btnSaveData" />
                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="return Cancel()" class="btnStyle" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult CheckCode(string type, string code)
{
    try
    {
        WCMSDataContext wcmsContext = new WCMSDataContext();

        if (type == "Data")
        {
            var Objp = from p in wcmsContext.Packages.Where(p => p.Code == code && p.Type == "Data") select p;
            if (Objp.Count() > 0)
            {
                return Json("failed");
            }
        }

        return Json("success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `jquery-validation-unobtrusive` and the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request for validation the email is asynchronous (read about common problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)) so it doesn't stop execution of the code below and the form is submitted. Also `return false` code is in other function and won't stop form submitting.

Here is what can be done:

**First option:** Make the ajax call synchronous. Define `isValid` variable. When the request is completed assign value to `isValid`. Then check if `isValid` is false and stop form from submitting.

```
$('#signupform').submit(function () {

    var isValid = false;

    var code = $('#txtcode').val();
    alert(code);
    if (code.length > 0) {
        //validate email
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("CheckCode", "Home"))",
            data: {
                "code": code,
                "type": "Data"
            },
            success: function (returndata) {
                if (returndata.match('success')) {
                    alert(returndata);
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        });

        if (!isValid)
           return false;
    }
});
```

**Second option:** Add 'btnSubmit' id to submit btn for easier DOM manipulation. Remove submit event from the form. Attach click event for submit button. Prevent it's default behavior. Check send asynchronous request to check validity. In success callback check if data is valid and if it's valid submit the form.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    var code = $('#txtcode').val();

    if (code.length > 0) {
        //validate email
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@(Url.Action("CheckCode", "Home"))",
            data: {
                "code": code,
                "type": "Data"
            },
            success: function (returndata) {
                if (returndata.match('success')) {
                    $('#signupform').submit();
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
});
```

I assume that validation should be done only if `code.length > 0` but if the validation should be done always move the `return false` part after this if condition.

**Note:** If the validation is only for 'valid email' it can be done on client side via javascript without server requests. Server request for validity should be done for uniqueness of email for example.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default to stop the form from doing a postback. Check below for updated code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#signupform').submit(function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
            var code = $('#txtcode').val();
            alert(code);
            if (code.length > 0) {

                //validate email
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("CheckCode", "Home"))",
                    data: {
                        "code": code,
                        "type": "Data"
                    },
                    success: function (returndata) {
                        if (returndata.match('failed')) {
                            alert(returndata);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }                    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok you code works when return is failed but else case does not work. it stops to submit the form in both cases.